# FreeBSD for java hosting

Tags: java, hosting, freebsd

I'm developing web application on java and in the nearest future I will host it.
I have experience only with Windows but host application I want on Unix system. My choice fell on FreeBSD. Is it good choice? If anybody have experience or can advice something?I will be grateful.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281555/how-good-is-freebsd-as-a-development-platform

Comment: The only experience I have in Java + FreeBSD is that it took 3 days to install Java 1.4 on a FreeBSD box using ports and required 3 times of kernel re-compiling :) But it was 6 years ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I am aware, all JVMs for FreeBSD are third party ports and there is no directly vendor supported JVM available for this platform.  Although there is a [port maintained within the FreeBSD ports library](http://www.freebsd.org/java/) it has no direct support from Sun/Oracle.

I don't think Java on FreeBSD is widely used as a platform.  You can use it and the FreeBSD folks claim the port is stable and (given the standards normally applied to stability in BSD circles) this is a reasonably credible claim.  However Java is much more widely used on Linux and has much better support on that platform.  You might be better off with Linux if you want to host a Java application.

Comment: Thank you, I will investigate Linux